# Jinja2, JavaScript and CSP

Tags: javascript, jinja2, content-security-policy

I've been studying Flask and Jinja2 for a while now, and I notice that all the books and tutorials I've found put `{% block js %}` *after* `{% block body %}`. This appears to violate CSP which, as I understand it, dictates that all javascript code be in external files and that the `<script>` tags which include those files be inside the page's `<head>` block. Is it possible/safe to put my `{% block js %}` inside my base template's `<head>` block, or am I somehow shooting myself in the foot if I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using your own base template, you are defining the blocks so you can arrange them any way that makes sense; in particular you can replace

```
{% block body %}
...
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
{{ super() }}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor')
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

with the CSP-compliant version

```
{% block js %}
{{ super() }}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ckinit.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
...
```

where `js/ckinit.js` consists of

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

function init(){
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
}
```

Note that if you are using a template package this may not work; in particular Flask-Bootstrap's `bootstrap/base.html` places `{% block scripts %}` between the `</body>` and `</html>` tags.